# Mongoid 5 has_many order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following setup:

```
class Evaluation
  include Mongoid::Document
  default_scope -> { order("_id ASC") }

  has_many :children, order: "position ASC"
end

class Child
  include Mongoid::Document
  default_scope -> { order("_id ASC") }

  field position, type: Integer, default: 0
end
```

When I call `evaluation.children`, the `position` order is not respected. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
has_many :children, order: :position.asc
```